# Question from Messiah's Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction

The question that I don't even know where to start on is as follows:
Utilizing the fact that any wave can be considered as a superposition of plane waves, show that in the absence of a field, the matter wave $\psi(\mathbf r_2,t_2)$ at the point $\mathbf r_2$ at the instant $t_2$ can be deduced from the values $\psi(\mathbf r_1,t_1)$ taken by the wave at the instant $t_1$, by the operation $$\psi(\mathbf r_2,t_2) = \int K(\mathbf r_2 -\mathbf r_1;t_2-t_1)\psi(\mathbf r_1,t_1) d\mathbf r_1$$ where $$K(\mathbf \rho;\tau) = (2\pi\hbar)^{-3}\int \exp[\frac i\hbar(\mathbf p*\mathbf\rho -E\tau)]d\mathbf p$$ (where $x*y$ is the  dot product) an expression in which $E$, a function of $\mathbf p$ is equal to the total energy of the particle, corresponding to the momentum $\mathbf p$. Show that for a non-relativistic particle of mass $m$, $$K(\rho;\tau) =\exp(-\frac 34 \pi i) (\frac m{2\pi\hbar\tau})^{\frac 32}\exp(i\frac{m\rho^2}{2\hbar\tau})$$ this is only part of the question, but I am clueless.

Comment: What have you tried? The question talks about superpositions of plane waves, maybe you should see if you can verify this for a single plane wave?

Comment: @jacob1729 That's the thing, I don't even see how I would do that!

Comment: 1) Consider a single planewave $\psi(r,t)$, momentum $p$, energy $E_p$. 2) Think about how it changes if you change only $r$ OR $t$. For instance, what does the Schroedinger equation tell you about $\psi(r,t')$?